# Grouping the arguments in argument parser

Tags: python

I have a script named Myscript.py which accept following arguments

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("MyParams")
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--info', dest='info',  help='info help', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--config', dest='config',  help='config help', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--number', dest='number',  help='numver help', required=True)
```

i also have a parameter -d as given below

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dest', dest='dest',  help='dest help', required=True)
```

i want to update my script to get either -a -b and -c together or -d alone.ie if i pass -d then i cannot pass -a or -b or -c .is it possible without changing the required=False

script commandline shouldbe either

```
Myscript.py -d "inputFile"
```

or

```
Myscript.py -a "inputFile1" -b "inputFile2" -c "inputFile3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure that this is an easy thing to do with `argparse` -- either an option is required, or it isn't.  You can't toggle it based on what else is there.

You can [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) but that doesn't help you here -- It's a pick one (and only one) out of the bag kind of thing.

Generally, I don't think it really handles mutually "inclusive" arguments very well.  I think that in this case, you're best bet is post-processing:

```
namespace = parser.parse_args()
if namespace.d is None:
    assert namespace.a is not None and namespace.b is not None and namespace.c is not None
else:
    assert namespace.a is namespace.b is namespace.c is None
```

And you can raise any error you want here (or even [`parser.error`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error)), `assert` is simply the quickest to write.

Comment: will adding "parser.add_subparsers()" help me here?

Comment: @user1654136 -- I don't think so.  The subparsers still don't do mutual inclusion.  In principle, you could separate the program into `prog.py subparser_d` and `prog.py subparser_e -a -b -c`, (with `a,b,c` all required).